# how to hide blank columns in power bi matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, report, dax

i have the below matrix, i need to hide "Budget" and "% Achieved to budget" when they are blank or 0.
for example in the below screen shot, they should only be displayed for year 2021, for the remaining years only "Actual" value should be shown.

[image]

appreciate your assistance
Georges

Answer (score 0):

You should add a filter using Budget and % Achieved and unselect Empty in options given.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 **Measures** for your **Actual, Budget and Percentage** following logic as below-

```
sum_actual = IF(
    SUM('your_table_name'[actual]) > 0,
    SUM('your_table_name'[actual]),
    BLANK()
)
```

This will return BLANK when there is no value. Now use those measures for Metrix property and hopefully you will get your desired output.

Comment: but should i hide the column if they are blank?

Comment: There is no logic of hiding columns (Which is not achievable dynamically as well). This will also misdirect end user in some cases.

Comment: its the user who requested it, since budget is only for year 2021, there is no use to display empty columns for the rest of years

Comment: Then hide all columns belongs to other Years by adding Visual level filter on Year value.

Comment: I have added a power bi [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68508410/6854117) can you please see it  ?